# not to read empty or null records in datatble from text file - c#

Tags: c#, asp.net, datatable, csv

I have a `function` which reads all the `tab delimited` records from a text file into a `datatble`, but I have a lot empty or null columns also which are `tab delimited`. I just want to read all records where column 3 is not null or non empty. how can I do it?
Here is my simple method

```
public DataTable ConvertTextToDataTable(string filePath, int numberOfColumns)
    {
        DataTable tbl = new DataTable();

        for (int col = 0; col < numberOfColumns; col++)
            tbl.Columns.Add(new DataColumn("Column" + (col + 1).ToString()));


        string[] lines = System.IO.File.ReadAllLines(filePath);
        int i = 0;
        foreach (string line in lines)
        {
            var cols = line.Split('\t');

            DataRow dr = tbl.NewRow();
            for (int cIndex = 0; cIndex < numberOfColumns; cIndex++)
            {
                dr[cIndex] = cols[cIndex];
            }

            tbl.Rows.Add(dr);
            i++;
        }
        return tbl;
    }
```

Comment: In addition to Habibs answer you could check out [TextFieldParser](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/microsoft.visualbasic.fileio.textfieldparser%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) for reading and splitting.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The simplest would be to insert a check for `IsNullOrWhiteSpace` for column 3 before creating and and adding values to the datatable like:

```
public DataTable ConvertTextToDataTable(string filePath, int numberOfColumns)
{
    DataTable tbl = new DataTable();

    for (int col = 0; col < numberOfColumns; col++)
        tbl.Columns.Add(new DataColumn("Column" + (col + 1).ToString()));


    var lines = System.IO.File.ReadLines(filePath);
    int i = 0;
    foreach (string line in lines)
    {
        var cols = line.Split('\t');

        if (cols.Length > 3 && String.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(cols[3]))
        {
            continue; //Ignore this line 

        }
        DataRow dr = tbl.NewRow();
        for (int cIndex = 0; cIndex < numberOfColumns; cIndex++)
        {
            dr[cIndex] = cols[cIndex];
        }

        tbl.Rows.Add(dr);
        i++;
    }
    return tbl;
}
```

Also notice the use of `var lines = System.IO.File.ReadLines(filePath);` instead of `File.ReadAllLines`, since it will evaluate the file line by line, instead of loading up all the files content in memory.